# How can I find my 'Shared secret' after installing and configuring PiVPN?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

I've successfully installed and configured PiVPN. It works as VPN to connect to my home network. Now I want to know how I can find the 'shared secret' of this setup?

When I want to connect my VPN to my cloud provider it's asking for the shared secret.

Comment: Your pivpn server provides VPN access to your home loan from outside. It doesn't have anything to do with VPN services somewhere on the internet.  At least, that's my understanding. I run a PiHole with inbound and Wireguard on a pi4b on my LAN. I can connect to my LAN from anywhere on the internet and thus pretend I'm at home when e.g. I access the internet and circumvent geo-blocking.

Comment: I would have edited spelling errors and clsrified but the application on my smartphone doesn't provide that function unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

shared secret usually refers to your password. you would need to contact your vpn provider if you lost that. to list certificates, type pivpn -l in the terminal.

Comment: I've setup my own VPN using Strongswan but I still don't understand where I can find my "shared key" or which setting is referring to it.